# Very High Network bandwidth usage (almost 20 GByte/Hour) Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: networking, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

My server provider sent me an email with PRTG network moniter report saying that my outward traffic volume is too high (say 15GByte/Hour).
I checked my network consumption with resource monitor utility provided by windows os. I could see following processes
[Server Resource monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZBoT.png).

I could find that **sqlservr.exe Sending aprox 250,999 B/Sec or more not less**.
and **w3sp.exe Receiving 258,396 B/Sec or more not less**.
and network activity I/O is 4mbps.

Is this expected behavior? Is it sqlservr.exe/w3sp.exe which is causing this high bandwidth usage or anything else?

How to go about investigating the same.

I have little or no knowledge with networking. Pardon me.
Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, as the admin, you should know whether or not that is expected behaviour of your system, given its purpose and workload.

Comment: @womble  The asp web application running on server does not consume much bandwidth itself. So how do I find which thing is causing the same. Or the server is compromised? and if yes then what is to be done as a counter measure

Comment: the same as every server, iis has text logs, you can parse them easily and find it why

Comment: If the server is compromised, [there is a question for that](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server).

Comment: I'm not sure from reading your question, so I will ask.  Are SQL Server and IIS both installed on the same server?  I'm assuming that this is hardware you own at a Colo.

Comment: @RobPearson yeah both are installed on same server!

Comment: What does IIS use to communicate with SQL - is it TCP/IP?  Do you know if you're hitting the public IP or a private one?  Is your provider telling you that you are using too much internet-facing bandwidth, or is it possible that they are telling you that you're using a bunch of local bandwidth?